# Ordering differences between ordered numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Consider 2 sets of numbers $\{a_1,...,a_J\}$ and $\{b_1,...,b_J\}$.

**(A1)** We know that $a_1<...<a_J$ and $b_1<...<b_J$.

Now consider the $J^2$ differences of each element of the first set with each element of the second set: 
$$
a_1-b_1\\
a_1-b_2\\
...\\
a_1-b_J\\
a_2-b_1\\
a_2-b_2\\
...\\
a_2-b_J\\
...\\
a_J-b_J
$$

Does **(A1)** allow to *order from smallest to largest* the differences? If not, does **(A1)** allow to say which is the *biggest and the smallest* difference? If not, does **(A1)** allow to *say anything* about the ordering of the differences?

(suggestions on more appropriate tags are welcome!)

Comment: Do we know anything about the numbers in the sets? Like are they naturals, integers, quotients etc?

Comment: No, they are just real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you arrange the differences $a_i-b_j$ in an $J\times J$ grid so that the $(i,j)$ entry is $a_i-b_j$, then the rows will increases from left to right and the columns will increase from top to bottom. If an entry $x$ is to the right of and below an entry $y$, then you know $x\ge y$. However, this is all you know about the ordering. For any entries $z$ and $w$ where $z$ is strictly to the right of and strictly above $w$, you do not know the ordering of $z$ and $w$.

In particular, the smallest entry is $a_1-b_J$, and the largest is $a_J-b_1$.